# How to print out the indexes of an array object in JSTL

Tags: java, html, arrays, jstl

I have a problem here in JSTL, I have an array object coming from a request attribute that was set in a servlet. All I want to do is to print the indexes of the array. Any help please? Here's the code:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/Functions" prefix="func"%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>k</b> = 
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${responseVector.length}">
                <tr>
                    <td>k<sub>${i}</sub></td><!-- I wish to print the indexes here -->
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <c:forEach var="i" items="${responseVector}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${func:roundOff(i, 4)}</td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
```

In the code above, responseVector is a double array object, but I want the variable i in the first loop to print the indexes of the array object each time the loop iterates. My expected output is: k0, k1, k2, ... but am having an exception instead.

Comment: What exception your'e getting?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasPerException at line 17 14: 15: 16: 17: 18: 19: 20:

Comment: @Jevison7x Not the most helpful information; what does that mean?

Comment: I have no idea. Should I paste the complete Stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (Use `varStatus` attribute)

```
<c:forEach items="${responseVector}" var="r" varStatus="status">
  <c:out value="${status.index}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

`${status.index}` will give you:

> Retrieves the index of the current round of the iteration. If
>   iteration is being performed over a subset of an underlying array,
>   java.lang.Collection, or other type, the index returned is absolute
>   with respect to the underlying collection. Indices are 0-based.

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#getIndex%28%29).

Comment: This seems like a great idea, let me try it and see... Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a little help from Paulius Matulionis' Suggestion. here's the correct code I used:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : DisplayResponseVector
    Created on : Sep 14, 2012, 5:33:41 PM
    Author     : Jevison7x
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/Functions" prefix="func"%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>k</b> = 
        </td>
        <td> 
            <table border="1">
                <c:forEach var="i" items="${responseVector}" varStatus="sub">
                <tr>
                    <td>k<sub>${sub.count - 1}</sub></td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
             = 
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <c:forEach var="i" items="${responseVector}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${func:roundOff(i, 4)}</td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
```

The code above got the job done perfectly! Thanks everyone.